# Prove $a\sin(\theta) + b\cos(\theta) \equiv R\sin(\theta + \alpha)$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

I've seen a similar question to this several times.

> Express $12\sin(\theta) + 5\cos(\theta)$ in the form $R\sin(\theta + \alpha)$

Which you would do

$$R = \sqrt{5^2 + 12^2} = 13$$
$$\alpha = \tan^{-1}(\frac{5}{12}) \approx 22.62 (4s.f.)$$
$$\therefore 12\sin(\theta) + 5\cos(\theta) = 13\sin(\theta + 22.62)$$

My question is what is the simpilest way to prove the equation.

$$a\sin(\theta) + b\cos(\theta) \equiv R\sin(\theta + \alpha)$$

*Where $\it{R = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$ and $\it{\alpha = \tan^{-1}(\frac{b}{a})}$*

Comment: $\alpha$ is not necessarily $\arctan\bigl(\frac ba\bigr)$, i.e. you do not necessarily  have $-\frac\pi2<\alpha<\frac\pi2$.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you, I didn't realise that. I apologise for the mistake

Comment: @Bernard Before I accept mvw's answer would you agree it is correct?

Comment: It's perfectly correct. Note, as an extension to my comment, thatone begins to solve with `arctan`, but the real equation is the system $\begin{cases}\cos\alpha=\frac5{13}\\\sin\alpha=\frac{12}{13}\end{cases}$, and depending on the signs of $\sin\alpha$ and $\cos\alpha$, the real solution may or may not be `arctan` (it's only equal mod $\pi$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using complex numbers and definitions it is straight forward:
\begin{align}
a \sin(\theta) + b \cos(\theta) 
& = a \frac{e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}}{2i}
+ b\frac{e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}{2} \\
&= \frac{(a+ib) e^{i\theta} - (a-ib) e^{-i\theta}}{2i} \\
&= \frac{ (R e^{i\alpha}) e^{i\theta} - (R e^{-i\alpha}) e^{-i\theta}}{2i} \\
&= \frac{ R e^{i\alpha} e^{i\theta} - R e^{-i\alpha} e^{-i\theta}}{2i} \\
&= R\frac{e^{i(\theta+\alpha)} - e^{-i(\theta+\alpha)}}{2i} \\
&= R \sin(\theta + \alpha)
\end{align}
where $R = \lvert a + i b \rvert = \lvert a - i b \rvert = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ and $\alpha$ is the angle of $a + i b$ in polar representation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Meant no disrespect asking for others to verify. Just don't know enough about maths to do it myself XD